# Creating a Custom UITabBar

Tags: ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

is it possible to create a custom looking UITabBar (UITabBarController)? I created a mockup of a tab bar for an app which looks like this http://cl.ly/5sxG I would like to turn this into an actual tab bar. How would I go about this? Setting an image instead of the black tint and custom colored buttons? Any tutorials, code examples, documentation links are all helpful.

Thanks!